# Android- Get GPS location

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

I'm doing a project where i need to get the gps location when an anomaly occurs.
How i call/start the gps location in a method inside my Anomaly class?
So i have a class Anomaly and i've used this class to get the gps location:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class GPS extends Activity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {


            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                textView.append("\n "+location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
         if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             requestPermissions(new String[]{
                     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                     Manifest.permission.INTERNET
             }, 10);
         }
        }else {
            updateGPS();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    updateGPS();
        }
    }

    public void updateGPS() {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 3600000, 0, locationListener);
    }

}
```

this is my class Anormaly (i'm a begginer so i don´t know what i should extend and if i need to start a new intent)

```
public class Anomaly extends AppCompatActivity{

private GPS gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data);
}

 public void abnormalHRDetected(int heartRateInt) {

    if (heartRateInt < 40 || heartRateInt > 120) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GPS.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish(); 
    }
 }
```

It's simple. I'm receiving the heart rate and i put that on a screen "data". When the value of the heart rate it's lower than 40 or bigger than 120 occurs an anomaly and i want get the gps location at the moment (to send to a data base not to put that on the screen) sorry about my english

Comment: Where this Anomaly class?

Comment: Updated @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I do not understand the question. What do you need help with exactly?

Comment: I see you have an instance of an activity stored in an other activity. Do not do that.

Comment: For now do not worry about any code. Just explain in words what your app does. What does the first screen look like? What can the user do? What happens when the "anomaly"  occurs? Does the app go to another screen? If necessary, draw mock screens in MS Paint or a similar app.

Comment: It's simple. I'm receiving the heart rate and i put that on a screen "data". When the value of the heart rate it's lower than 40 or bigger than 120 occurs an anomaly and i want get the gps location at the moment (to send to a data base not to put that on the screen) sorry about my  english

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you should give access_gps and access_finelocation permissions in your manifest file.

The below code may help you to fix your problem

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class GPS extends Activity {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private TextView textView;
Location cLocation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         requestPermissions(new String[]{
                 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                 Manifest.permission.INTERNET
         }, 10);
     }
    }else {
        cLocation = updateGPS();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                cLocation = updateGPS(); //In update gps method the textview will set to current lat & long values and it returns the current location to your cLocation variable, if you wana use that values further you can use with cLocation variable.
    }
}

public Location updateGPS() {
Location currentLocation;
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            textView.append("\n "+location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());
            currentLocation = location;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 3600000, 0, locationListener);
    }
return currentLocation;
}
```

}

Comment: Pleased explain in more detail how this code helps the OP.

Comment: And where do you have hide class name?

Answer (score -1):

Refer this link

https://github.com/HariKrish4/TurnNavigation

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 100;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        getDirections();
    }

    private void getDirections() {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=triplicane,chennai&destination=saidapet,chennai&sensor=false";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
                            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                                    .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
                            list = decodePoly(encodedString);

                            // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
                            mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                                    .addAll(list)
                            );
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        } else {
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
            putNavigationMarker();
            createLocationRequest();
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }else {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }


    private void putNavigationMarker() {
        LatLng mapCenter = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapCenter, 13));

        // Flat markers will rotate when the map is rotated,
        // and change perspective when the map is tilted.
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_navigation_black_48dp))
                .position(mapCenter)
                .flat(true)
                .rotation(245));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(mapCenter)
                .zoom(16)
                .bearing(90)
                .build();

        // Animate the change in camera view over 2 seconds
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
                2000, null);

    }

    public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition,
                              final boolean hideMarker) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
        final long duration = 500;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);
                double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarker) {
                        marker.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                            mGoogleApiClient);
                    putNavigationMarker();
                } else {
                    // permission denied
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        LatLng mapCenter = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        animateMarker(marker,mapCenter,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this will help the OP.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Please refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: I am not the OP. I am giving a suggestion to improve your answer. This much code without any explanation is unhelpful.

Comment: Copy pasting some code that is completely irrelevant to the issue is less helpful than posting nothing. This question has nothing to do with a map, yet you provide code for it. Looks like it's copy pasted from an own project.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to use the code below, use  the interface `LocationListener` like a parameter. That way you don´t need to start Activity to get Location as in the original code.

Make sure you give ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions on your manifest file.

```
public class LocationSuporte
{
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;
    private final static String TAG = "Location Suporte";
    private Context mContext;


    public LocationSuporte(Context mContext, LocationListener mLocationListener) {
        this.mLocationListener = mLocationListener;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public boolean isGPSEnable() {
        LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return lManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || lManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }


    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }   

    public Location getLocation() {
        Location location = null;
        LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, 
                                                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  &&
                                                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
                                                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            return null;
        }

        try {
            boolean isGPSEnabled = this.isGPSEnable();
            Log.d(TAG, "isGPSEnabled = " + isGPSEnabled);

            boolean isNetworkEnabled = isNetworkAvailable();
            Log.d(TAG, "isNetworkEnabled = " + isNetworkEnabled);

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this.mLocationListener);
                if (lManager != null) {
                    location = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }
            }

            if (isGPSEnabled && location == null) {
                lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this.mLocationListener);
                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                if (lManager != null) {
                    location = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lManager.removeUpdates(this.mLocationListener);
        return location;
    }    
}
```

Use example;

```
 public void abnormalHRDetected(int heartRateInt)
 {
    if (heartRateInt < 40 || heartRateInt > 120) {
            Location location = new LocationSuporte(getApplicationContext(), new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.d("EXAMPLE","onLocationChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                Log.d("EXAMPLE","onStatusChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                Log.d("EXAMPLE","onProviderEnabled");

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Log.d("EXAMPLE","onProviderDisabled");
            }
        }).getLocation();

        Log.d("EXAMPLE","\n "+location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail his this solves the OP's problem. Also, give the specific permissions required.

Comment: Edit your question to improve it.

Comment: The necessary permission are
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

I just suggest another way to take Location I don´t understand what you need exactly .

Comment: That information belongs in your answer, not a comment. You also need to explain how your answer solves the OP's problem. What are you adding or changing in the original code posted in the question?